# Combining two sql columns into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with two columns, both of them contains integer values, that looks like this:

```
DocumentUpId    RelatedDocId
31608768        31624333
31608768        31624334
31618133        31618117
```

And I am trying to merge them into a single column like so:

```
DocumentUpId    
31608768        
31608768        
31618133    
31624333
31624334
31624334
```

I have tried this:

```
select rel_CTE.DocumentUpId + rel_CTE.DocumentDownId as 'RelatedDocId' 
into #temprelations 
from RelationsCTE rel_CTE
```

But it gives me concatenate of values (well sum in this case), so is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UNION ALL

```
select rel_CTE.DocumentUpId  as 'RelatedDocId'  from RelationsCTE
union all
select rel_CTE.DocumentDownId from RelationsCTE
```

Answer (score 4):

Try like this,

```
SELECT DocumentUpId as DocumentUpId 
FROM RelationsCTE

UNION ALL

SELECT DocumentDownId as DocumentUpId 
FROM RelationsCTE
```

Comment: `union` will not give the correct results as it filters duplicate values.

Comment: don't really understand the down vote for something that's easily corrected within a reasonable time frame, what's the point? have a +1 from me

Comment: @Tanner: And what I want to know is why these easy questions/answers get so many votes (both up and down), and then those that answer difficult questions barely get any upvotes. I think I know the answer to that, but still...

Comment: @sstan that's the way of the world. the suggested duplicate was too late and not really a suitable candidate, but that would have been the way to go. it's not too late to close.

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing different using CROSS -APPLY :).

```
SELECT [RelatedDocId]  
FROM RelationsCTE 
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DocumentUpId),
                     (DocumentDownId)) V( [RelatedDocId])
```